# How to clean data by removing invalide values from dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
ID,age,salary,suburb,language
P1,eighty two,60196.0,Toorak,English
P2,49,-16945514.0,St. Kilda,Chinese
P3,54,49775.0,Neverland,Italian
```

I have the above dictionary. In the age column, some ages are written in words. I want to replace them with `None`.

Similarly in second column salary is negative or more than Max-salary that needs to be replaced by `None`, and there are invalid suburbs name that need to be changed to `None` as well.

Comment: What kind of suburb names are considered invalid?

Comment: Please show what you have tried and what errors (if any) you got.

Comment: The valid suburbs are listed in a variable called VALIDSUBURBS. any name not given in the valid suburbs willbe considered as invalid and need to be changed to NONe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not completely clear on how this data is stored, since each row has 5 entries and a dictionary normally consists of key-value pairs. I will assume that the `ID` is used as a key and the other four entries are stored in an object as members, with this object as the value. I will refer to this dictionary as `dict` If you are expecting ages to be an integer number of years, and max salary is stored in `max_salary`, then the following should work:

```py
for ID in dict.keys():
  age, salary = dict[ID].age, dict[ID].salary
  if not isinstance(age, int) or age < 0:
    dict[ID].age = None
  if salary < 0 or salary > max_salary:
    dict[ID].salary = None
```

If you started with a list of rows in a file, then the file could be opened and read into such a dictionary like this (with the first part borrowed from [Kingsley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1730895/kingsley)'s answer):

```py
class PersonData(object):
  def __init__(self, age, salary, suburb, language):
    self.age = age
    self.salary = salary
    self.suburb = suburb
    self.language = language

file=open("people_data.txt", "rwt")
dict = {}
for row in file.readlines():
  try:
    ID, age, salary, suburb, language = row.split(",")
    dict[ID] = PersonData(age, salary, suburb, language)
  except:
    print("Invalid data: "+row)
    row = None
```

Then after the check, the file could be overwritten with the new data:

```py
file.seek(0) # go to file beginning
for ID in dict.keys():
  age, salary, suburb, language = dict[ID].age, dict[ID].salary, \
    dict[ID].suburb, dict[ID].language
  file.write(str(ID)+','+str(age)+','+str(salary)+',' \
            +str(suburb)+','+str(language)+'\n')
file.close()
```

Comment: I guess depending on whether you had the data in memory or in a file, you might need to read the data into that format and then write it back out to a file. I have edited the answer to include this

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple to split your list up, then do something to each field.
There's lots of minor errors to catch (like if your salary is not a number), but below is a simple example of this sort of processing.

```
ok_suburbs = [ 'Toorak', 'St. Kilda', 'Redfern' ]

# Read list of data into <people>
people = open("people_data.txt", "rt").readlines()
del(people[0])  # remove the header

for row in people:
    try:
        id, age, salary, suburb, language = row.split(",")
    except:
        print("Invalid data: "+row)
        row = None

    if row != None:
        try:
            age = str(int(age))
        except:
            age = None
        salary = float(salary)
        if salary < 0:
            salary = None
        if suburb not in ok_suburbs:
            suburb = None
        # TODO - rebuild the row from parts
```

You should be handling edge-conditions like - bad numbers, excess spaces on fields, case in SuBUrB NamEs, too few fields, too many fields, etc.